How to determine the input stack format for a Miniscript script?
Is there an exact "calling convention" produced when you compile a policy? I am guessing this information must be available somewhere since the compiler has to perform its own validity analysis. I would just like to know exactly what I have to put in the witness stack to unlock the output without trying to figure it out from the script.

Yes. This is one of the main purposes of Miniscript to make it possible to construct witnesses in a general yet safe manner. The satisfaction table in the Miniscript BIP defines the witness stack element(s) to satisfy each fragment.
